# How to declare multiple header & multiple source section in single make File to create multiple Targets

Tags: c++, makefile, build, gnu-make

I have single make file. But I want to create multiple targets.
For example-

```
A1.h A1.c
B1.h B1.c
C1.h C1.c
```

```
include= A1.h
src = A1.c
```

from these two file one targets I want to create

```
include= B1.h
src = B1.c
```

from these two file another targets I want to create

```
include= C1.h
src = C1.c
```

from these two file another targets I want to create

But all I want to do from a single make file . So how to declare multiple includes and Src section , so that each include and src points to different values.

Comment: Please, show (add to the question post) how do you create a single target in a Makefile. As currently written, it is difficult to understand what sort of targets do you want and how variables `include` and `src` are related to them.

Answer (score 0):

You could have rules like

```
a: A1.o
A1.o: A1.c A1.h
```

Then just run `make a` to create `a` from the `A1` source and header files.

Do the same for `B1` and `C1`, in the same makefile.